# Docker pull not getting image tagnames

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm running docker with boot2docker on OS X 10.10.

I'm following the [main tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/) and doing a `docker pull ubuntu`

It gets the image okay, however when I then do `docker images` it only lists ubuntu:latest

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu              latest              5506de2b643b        3 weeks ago         199.3 MB
```

instead of the full list of images as the tutorial says:

```
REPOSITORY       TAG      IMAGE ID      CREATED      VIRTUAL SIZE
training/webapp  latest   fc77f57ad303  3 weeks ago  280.5 MB
ubuntu           13.10    5e019ab7bf6d  4 weeks ago  180 MB
ubuntu           saucy    5e019ab7bf6d  4 weeks ago  180 MB
ubuntu           12.04    74fe38d11401  4 weeks ago  209.6 MB
ubuntu           precise  74fe38d11401  4 weeks ago  209.6 MB
ubuntu           12.10    a7cf8ae4e998  4 weeks ago  171.3 MB
ubuntu           quantal  a7cf8ae4e998  4 weeks ago  171.3 MB
ubuntu           14.04    99ec81b80c55  4 weeks ago  266 MB
ubuntu           latest   99ec81b80c55  4 weeks ago  266 MB
ubuntu           trusty   99ec81b80c55  4 weeks ago  266 MB
ubuntu           13.04    316b678ddf48  4 weeks ago  169.4 MB
ubuntu           raring   316b678ddf48  4 weeks ago  169.4 MB
ubuntu           10.04    3db9c44f4520  4 weeks ago  183 MB
ubuntu           lucid    3db9c44f4520  4 weeks ago  183 MB
```

If I do `docker images -a` I see this:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu              latest              5506de2b643b        3 weeks ago         199.3 MB
<none>              <none>              22093c35d77b        3 weeks ago         199.3 MB
<none>              <none>              3680052c0f5c        3 weeks ago         192.7 MB
<none>              <none>              e791be0477f2        3 weeks ago         192.7 MB
<none>              <none>              ccb62158e970        3 weeks ago         192.7 MB
<none>              <none>              d497ad3926c8        3 weeks ago         192.5 MB
<none>              <none>              511136ea3c5a        17 months ago       0 B
```

Anybody knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `docker pull <image>` you will only get the `latest` tag for that image. This is expected behaviour.

To pull a specific tag, use `docker pull <image>:<tag>`.

The list there in the documentation should only be expected if you've followed the full guide and used all those images. You usually only need one tag for an image.